# Advice for keeping python logging script running indefinitely. Script acts up after many hours

Tags: python, windows, logging, raspberry-pi, scheduling

I'm writing a script to log serial data from a solar inverter. The script runs fine for many hours on windows, but then starts to act up.

The script should print debug data to console and write logging data to a .csv file roughly every minute.

1. Printing debug data to stdout works for hours, but then starts to become sporadic. When I mouse over the PowerShell console and bring it into focus again the printing seems to resume. Does Windows put old/inactive processes to sleep or something?
2. The script should write logging data to a .csv file roughly every minute, however it sometimes goes many minutes without updating the .csv file. <s>When it does finally update the file no data is lost, so its still clearly logging data in the backround.</s> Edit: looking closer at the .csv data, it appears there are in fact temporal breaks in the data, where I assume the process is being suspended and then later resumed.

I've been programming for years, but I am new to python. I'm sure I haven't made an overflow error or something similar. I don't think you'll glean anything from it, but I've put the main loop of the script below anyways.

```py
try:
    if not ser.is_open:
        print("Opening Serial")
        ser.open()

    # global inverterSettings
    inverterSettings = crc.readSettings(ser)

    qpigsColumns = dp.qpigsParamsModified.keys()
    print("qpigsColumns:\n", qpigsColumns)
    qpigsArray = pd.DataFrame([], columns=qpigsColumns)
    qpigsArray.set_index("24hDecimal", inplace=True)

    today = time.strftime(
        "%a, %d %b %Y", time.localtime()
    )  # nicely formatted date variable
    print("Sarting @ " + today)

    while 1:

        newToday = time.strftime(
            "%a, %d %b %Y", time.localtime()
        )  # checking for a new day every minute or so
        if today != newToday:
            today = newToday  # updating to new day
            qpigsArray = pd.DataFrame(
                [], columns=qpigsColumns
            )  # creating new dataFrame for new day
            qpigsArray.set_index("24hDecimal", inplace=True)
            print("\n" + today)

        # read solar data loop
        # --------------------
        print(".", end="", flush=True)

        for i in range(30):
            rawQpigsData = dp.readQPIGS(ser)
            data = pd.DataFrame([rawQpigsData], columns=qpigsColumns)
            data.set_index("24hDecimal", inplace=True)
            qpigsArray = qpigsArray.append(data, ignore_index=False)

        qpigsArray.to_csv(today + ".csv")

        # ---------

        if (rawQpigsData[-1] > 6) and (
            rawQpigsData[-1] < 18
        ):  # between 6 am and 6 pm (daylight hours)
            if (rawQpigsData[13] > PVocV / 2) and (
                rawQpigsData[15] < 10
            ):  # Panels have enough voltage, but not producing any solar power
                print("?", end="", flush=True)
                floatV = inverterSettings["userSettings"]["floatChargeV"]
                rx1 = crc.adjustFloatV(
                    (floatV - 0.1), ser
                )  # potential fix for panels not working?
                rx2 = crc.adjustFloatV((floatV + 0.1), ser)
                if rx1 == rx2 == "Ack":
                    print("?", end="", flush=True)
                else:
                    print("¿", end="", flush=True)
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
finally:
    ser.close()
```

The script doesn't seem to crash or throw any errors. So I'm assuming this is a error with the way Windows handles long running processes. I plan to move this to a r-pi soon btw.

So in general, I need advice on how to set up python code so it can run indefinitely on windows and on a r-pi without being put to sleep, or crashing after months. How does one usualy go about this?

Comment: Have you considered to remove the loop and trigger the script from the OS?

Comment: It really shouldn't get suspended. But you might try using a `sleep` in the while-loop. Is the script always at 100% CPU?